# Can we use k-means clustering on this matrix

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means

The following rows represent temperatures from -40 to 400 degrees and the 7 columns represent type of thermocouples(B,J,K....)

**![temperature vs emf matrix][1]**

```
X=[   -1.961 -1.527 -0.194 -1.475 -1.023 -0.188 -2.255
      -1.482 -1.156 -0.150 -1.121 -0.772 -0.145 -1.709
      -0.995 -0.778 -0.103 -0.757 -0.518 -0.100 -1.152
      -0.501 -0.392 -0.053 -.0383 -0.260 -0.051 -0.582
       0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000
       0.507  0.397  0.055  0.391  0.261  0.054  0.591
       1.019  0.798  0.113  0.790  0.525  0.111  1.192
       1.537  1.203  0.17   1.196  0.793  0.171  1.801
       2.059  1.612  0.235  1.612  1.065  0.232  2.420
       2.585  2.023  0.299  2.036  1.340  0.296  3.048
       3.116  2.436  0.365  2.468  1.619  0.363  3.685
       3.650  2.851  0.433  2.909  1.902  0.431  4.330
       4.187  3.267  0.502  3.358  2.189  0.501  4.985
       4.726  3.682  0.573  3.814  2.480  0.573  5.648
       5.269  4.096  0.646  4.279  2.774  0.647  6.319
       5.814  4.509  0.720  4.750  3.071  0.723  6.998
       6.360  4.920  0.795  5.228  3.374  0.800  7.685
       6.909  5.328  0.872  5.714  3.680  0.879  8.379
       7.459  5.735  0.950  6.206  3.989  0.959  9.081
       8.010  6.138  1.029  6.704  4.302  1.041  9.789
       8.562  6.540  1.110  7.209  4.618  1.124 10.503
       9.115  6.941  1.191  7.720  4.937  1.208 11.224
       9.669  7.340  1.273  8.237  5.259  1.294 11.951
       10.224 7.739  1.357  8.759  5.585  1.381 12.684
       10.779 8.138  1.441  9.288  5.913  1.469 13.421
       11.334 8.539  1.526  9.822  6.245  1.558 14.164
       11.889 8.940  1.612  10.362 6.579  1.648 14.912
       12.445 9.343  1.698  10.907 6.916  1.739 15.664
       13.000 9.747  1.786  11.458 7.255  1.831 16.420
       13.555 10.153 1.874  12.013 7.597  1.923 17.181
       14.110 10.561 1.962  12.574 7.941  2.017 17.945
       14.665 10.971 2.052  13.139 8.288  2.112 18.713
       15.219 11.382 2.141  13.709 8.637  2.207 19.484
       15.773 11.795 2.232  14.283 8.988  2.304 20.259
       16.327 12.209 2.323  14.862 9.341  2.410 21.036
       16.881 12.624 2.415  15.445 9.696  2.498 21.817
       17.434 13.040 2.507  16.032 10.054 2.597 22.600
       17.986 13.457 2.599  16.624 10.413 2.696 23.386
       18.538 13.874 2.692  17.219 10.774 2.796 24.174
       19.090 14.293 2.786  17.819 11.136 2.896 24.964
       19.642 14.713 2.880  18.422 11.501 2.997 25.757
       20.194 15.133 2.974  19.030 11.867 3.099 26.552
       20.745 15.554 3.069  19.641 12.234 3.201 27.348
       21.297 15.975 3.164  20.255 12.603 3.304 28.146
       21.848 16.397 3.259  20.872 12.974 3.408 28.946];
```

**My question is :** Can we use clustering algorithms on such type of matrices when all the column contains the same entity at different states ?

If not, then what could be the possible methods for identification?

Comment: Yes we can! - BHObama

Answer (score 0):

Generally - yes, you can use clustering algorithms on data, where features are strongly correlated - the only problem is - what are you actually trying to capture?

The most basic preprocessing method which can somewhat deal with correlation between features is transforming your data through cov(X)^(-1/2) (square root of the inverse of data covariance matrix). As a result you get data with identity correlation matrix, which is more suitable for scale-variant clustering methods. Such result can be obtained directly by using Mahalanobis k-means (which does exactly this).

Answer (score 0):

Well, of course you *can* run k-means, *technically*.

The question that you should be asking yourself is: **what are you trying to do**?

K-means on this type of data will be heavily biased (because of redundancies; k-means is best run on whitened data, with unit variance and no covariance!), and it treats each point in time as instance, i.e. it will cluster *time*, but without any connectivity constraint. I.e. it will cluster individual measurements, but not intervals.

You may be more interested in *segmentation* of your data into convex segments, for example. Plus, you really need to pay attention what your individual attributes convey.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use highly correlated data you could use some type of dimensionality reduction technique (e.g., PCA) to simplify the dataset before you cluster it. However, as many others have suggested, you should really identify what you goal is first.